# ошибка при установке postgresql 10 на debian

Tags: postgresql, debian

не оч хорошо разбираюсь в установке на linux, делаю буквально по шажочкам. В процессе инсталляции после ввода psql вылетает `Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

вообще не понимаю, что делать дальше - подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: pg кластер не запущен -> нет сокета -> psql не может найти сокет

Comment: а как запустить этот кластер?

Comment: systemctl start <название юнита> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: ничего не пойму :( какой юнит?

Comment: скрипт управляющий жизнью процесса, ссылку для кого дал :)?

Comment: ищите в названии которого есть pgsql или что-то похожее - не помню название

Comment: итак, `systemctl start postgresql.service` - норм. затем сделал `systemctl status postgresql.service` ответ `postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-06-18 21:51:25 MSK; 1 day 2h ago
 Main PID: 19128 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Jun 18 21:51:25 -----.ru systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jun 18 21:51:25 -----.ru systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
`

Comment: потом `su - postgres` зашел. ну и наконец `psql` - вышеописанная ошибка `postgres@ovz1:~$ psql
Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
`

Comment: в /var/run/postgresql/ должен быть файл сокета .s.PGSQL.5432, если нет - искать в конфигах какой задан и задат в утилите psql

Comment: Опишите подробно как вы устанавливали и на каком этапе возникла ошибка.